# c++ eof and empty line confusion

Tags: c++, eof

```
string line;
getline (cin, line);
if(line.empty() && !cin.eof()) continue;
if (cin.eof()) {
    if (need_echo) cout << "^D";
    cout << endl;
    DEBUGF ('y', "EOF");
    break;
}
```

Why is `cin.eof` false when `getline(cin, line)` scans an empty line?

Comment: `cin.eof` should always return false, check the result of `getline(cin, line)` instead.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Unless you have a pipe or the user enters eof (ctrl-d in a linux terminal)

Comment: @DieterLücking Yes. That's why I wrote _should_, not _must_ or _will_ ... THX for the clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Because an EOF (End Of File) is different than the end of a line. You could have a file Thats filled with empty lines, for example: Just write many end of line characters.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "empty line"? Is the line void of characters whatsoever, or does it have a newline at the end? If the line really were empty `std::getline()` would've read the EOF and set `std::ios_base::eofbit` in the stream state of `std::cin`. If there was a newline at the end it would've reached the end of the input, but it would *not* have set the `eofbit`.